# access outer function variable in inner functions

Tags: lexical-closures

```
function Outer(){
var a=10;
function Inner(){
var a = 20;
console.log(a);
}
Inner();
}
Outer();
```

In this codek I want the inner function to print the value of outer function's a(i.e 10). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you delcare `var a = 20;` on the fourth line above, you're redeclaring a variable that is already in scope and assigning it a new value. So the new value is what you get. If you remove that declaration, the name `a` will refer to the variable declaration in the outer scope and you'll get 10.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've tried it but it's still printer the variable in the inner scope. I've found that bind() will helps to resolve this problem but i'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: You must not have tried the same thing I'm trying. Take a look at this example on jsbin where I commented out the inner variable declaration:
https://jsbin.com/taneyoviro/edit?html,output